# MessageFormat.format - what font size?

Tags: java, jfreechart, messageformat

I have a set of walk charts which are generated by Java. The labels of the entire chart are in Calibri 8 and consistent. Except for when the value is 0.00, which stands out in Arial 8.

I traced it down to this class:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class ItemLabelGen extends StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator {          
       public String GenLable(CategoryDataset ds, int row, int column) {
          Number num = ds.getValue(row, column);
          return MessageFormat.format("{0,number,#0.00}",num);
     }
```

}

So my question is, how can i control the font size or font itself here? the 0.00 is sticking out like a sore thumb and driving our folks frenzy here.

If I cannot control it in MessageFormat, is there any way, i can force it to use a specific font since I have the value?

Tia,
B

Comment: You traced it down wrong, that code fragment generates a `String`, which has nothing to do with fonts.

Comment: @Roman thanks for responding. I realize it has nothing to do with fonts, but it does generate a label correct? So, for that label, how can i control what font it should generate in?

Comment: 1. It generates a string, not a label. 2. It depends on how and where that label is rendered.

Comment: Yes @Roman. Thank you.

Comment: What `ChartTheme`?

Answer (score 1):

Tell the `BarRenderer` used by your chart's `CategoryPlot` to use the desired `Font`.

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 8));
```